# Adding removing leading and trailing spaces in this JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I add code to remove leading and trailing spaces to this regular expression?

I tried putting the `\s` in several places, but end up with odd results.

The `myString` is just the way it is, and is sent from a PHP script `with` trailing spaces.

Original Code

```
var myString = "::This is string 1 ::This is string 2! ";

myString = myString.replace(/\::(.+?)(?![^::])/g,'<li>$1</li>');

alert(myString);
```

Tried

```
var myString = "::This is string 1 ::This is string 2! ";

myString = myString.replace(/\::(.+?)(?![^::\s])/g,'<li>$1</li>');

alert(myString);
```

The end result I'm trying to achieve is

```
<li>This is string 1</li> // No trailing spaces before or after the `This` and `1`
<li>This is String 2</li>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2vnvwyd/)

Comment: Try [`::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/aC5uM2/1)

Comment: [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 4):

The point is that you match spaces with `.+?`, and `(?![^::\s])` only tells the regex engine to not match a character if it is followed by a whitespace or `:`.

Since you already are using lazy matching, you just need to use a greedy `\s*` subpattern to match whitespaces *after* the `.+?`.

Use

```
::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC5uM2/1)

**Explanation:**

- `::` - match 2 `:`s
- `(.+?)` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more characters other than a newline
- `\s*` - greedily match zero or more whitespaces
- `(?=::|$)` - only if followed by `::` or end of string.

And here is my attempt at unrolling the regex (looks a bit more efficient than the above):

```
::(\S*(?:(?=(\s+))\2(?!:|$)\S*)*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC5uM2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myString = "::This is string 1 ::This is string 2! ";

myString = myString.replace(/\s*\::\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(::|$))/g,'<li>$1</li>');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrwz6mvz/1/)